# Get current plugin name in plugin element CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am making a application where I need to create a element so that I can copy paste the element file into another plugin's element without changing anything.

For that I need to have a dynamic piece of code which can automatically have the current plugin directory name. I have looked all over for this solution but it seems that not much people have woked on CakePHP 3 or maybe its simple enough and I'm dumb to find it.

I tried using `$this->request` or `$this->params` but no luck with these.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$this->plugin` to have the current plugin directory name.

In fact even in future whenever you are stuck in a situation like this and you don't find any function to get information related to current plugin, controller, model etc., then you can simply print `$this` and see if it has the info related to what you want. If it has, then you can access the keys to have the value you want.

Comment: It works!! Thanks for the simple and precise answer. :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can choose this as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 4.4 (for googlers): use `$this->name`.